# stored procedure to display monday or weekday

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, xampp

I want to write a stored procedure to find out the joining date of teachers and if it is a Monday it should display Monday else it should display “Weekday”

The tbl_teacher table is ;

vchr_teacher_name    dat_teacher_doj

```
    teena             1982-01-10         
    lawrence          1979-09-01          
    mathew            1981-10-13            
    job               1980-11-12
```

and I need to create a stored procedure as " CALL CHECK_DATE(1982-01-10)" results as:

```
   day
----------
 weekday
----------
```

i tried  as :

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE check_date (IN dat date,OUT day varchar(10))

BEGIN

SELECT DAYNAME( dat ) INTO DAY FROM tbl_teachers;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

It's show the error as

```
#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row
```

How to do this and find the day is Monday or an weekday.

Comment: simply stored procedure to find the day from in parameter date

Answer (score -1):

I think you are better served with a [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS  `check_date` //

CREATE  FUNCTION `check_date` (dat date)
RETURNS varchar(10)
BEGIN
   return IF(dayname(dat) = 'Monday' , 'Monday', 'Weekday');
END //
```

I used the [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function to determine if a Monday or something else (Weekday) needs to returned.

And when use on your teacher table the result will be:

```
vchr_teacher_name  check_date(`dat_teacher_doj`)
------------------------------------------------
teena              Weekday 
Lawrence           Weekday 
mathew             Weekday 
job                Weekday 
mday               Monday
```

I have a full working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3507/1) for you to experiment with.